# Question about Mesquite signature size?

Tags: signature, multivariate-cryptography

I have a question regarding William Wang's paper [Shorter Signatures from MQ](https://eprint.iacr.org/2022/344.pdf). According to him the (maximum) signature size is:

$$
2\kappa +
3\kappa\cdot \lceil\tau\log\frac{M}{\tau}\rceil
+
\tau\cdot\left(
\kappa\log N
+ 2 \kappa
+ (n+m)\log q
\right)
$$

The parameters can be chosen in a variety of ways, in the paper the "compact" parameters are suggested (because they lead to smaller signatures at the cost of computation time):

- $\kappa=128$ is the security level.
- $N=16$.
- $M=232$.
- $\tau=36$.
- $n=m=88$.
- $q=4$.

In the paper he estimates the signature size with this parameters is $8.64$ KB. However, when I check the computation I get:
$9.68$ KB. So $1$ KB extra that comes out of nowhere.

I get a similar "overhead" when I try another set of parameters suggested in the paper.

Does anyone know where the difference comes from?

PS: This is the code I used.

```
import numpy as np

def bitToKB(bits):
    return bits / 8 / 1024


def offline_cost(M, kappa, tau):
    return 2 * kappa + 3 * kappa * np.ceil(tau * np.log2(M / tau))


"""
Computes the communication cost given
M
N,
kappa: Security level
"""


def communication(M, N, tau, n, m, q, kappa=128):

    offline = offline_cost(M, kappa, tau)
    cost_per_round = kappa * np.ceil(
        np.log2(N)) + 2 * kappa + (n + m) * np.log2(q)

    #Result is in bits. Be convert it to KB. For readability.
    return bitToKB(offline + tau * cost_per_round)


print("Mesquite")
params = {"M": 176, "N": 8, "tau": 51, "n": 88, "m": 88, "q": 4}
print("Fast")
print(communication(**params))
params = {"M": 232, "N": 16, "tau": 37, "n": 88, "m": 88, "q": 4}
print("Compact")
print(communication(**params))
```